# I don't understand what does ${} hold? Is it kind of some php way of storing array?

Tags: php

I have a code written. And i am trying to understand it. But i don't understand what does ${} hold? Is it kind of array?

```
$CategoriesRows = $current->getWorkgroupCategoryNames();        
 while ($line = mssql_fetch_row($CategoriesRows)){
    if (!empty(${trim($line[0])})){
        //processRequestAfterApproval(trim($line[0]), ${trim($line[0])}      ,$accessEmailBody);
        processRequestAfterApproval123(trim($line[0]), ${trim($line[0])} ,      $accessEmailBody);
    }
 }
```

Comment: `echo trim($line[0]); echo ${trim($line[0])}` would tell you quite quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a variable's variable thing..

See this below example for your understanding...

```
<?php
$hashd="hello";
$test=" hashd ";
echo ${trim($test)}; //"prints" hello
```

[`More examples in the PHP Manual !`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 7):

It's a variable variable. It's taking the result of `trim($line[0])` and using that as a variable name.

It is commonly seen when a programmer has never heard of an associative array.